# iOS - Init NSDate with a stringDate without timezone calculations

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting a date time from **web service** which is in **UTC** format. Now i want to assign it to NSDate. Following is the code i have done

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *utcDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-08-18T23:00:00"];
```

but it is calculating its timezone calculations by default the result is **2015-08-19 03:00:00 +0000**. How can i initialize NSDate with same date and Time. I want to perform timezone calculations later on

Comment: Uncomment that timezone line and set it to UTC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

edit/update:

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**:

```
let dateString = "2015-08-18T23:00:00"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
if let dateFromString = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
    print(dateFromString)   // "2015-08-18 23:00:00 +0000"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A default-allocated `NSDateFormatter` will use the current locale (the one that the user set up in Settings.app).

You have to explicitly set a suitable locale on the formatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

This locale uses the gregorian calendar on UTC without any DST adjustments.

Edit: LeoDabus points out that setting the `locale` does not change the `timezone` of the date formatter. This has to be done explicitly:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
```

Comment: A default-allocated NSDateFormatter will use the current locale (the one that the user set up in Settings.app). contradicts with This locale uses the gregorian calendar on UTC without any DST adjustments. Actually the later it is wrong. By default it will use current locale(local time not UTC). You need to specify  secondsFromGMT

Comment: @LeoDabus Not sure I understand the contradiction, but good point about the error with the offset from UTC. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

NSString *dateStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"utc_datetime"]];

```
NSString* input = dateStr;
NSString* format = @"dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss'";

// Set up an NSDateFormatter for UTC time zone
NSDateFormatter* formatterUtc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatterUtc setDateFormat:format];
[formatterUtc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

// Cast the input string to NSDate
NSDate* utcDate = [formatterUtc dateFromString:input];

// Set up an NSDateFormatter for the device's local time zone
NSDateFormatter* formatterLocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatterLocal setDateFormat:format];
[formatterLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

// Create local NSDate with time zone difference
NSDate* localDate = [formatterUtc dateFromString:[formatterLocal stringFromDate:utcDate]];
NSLog(@"utc:   %@", utcDate);
NSLog(@"local: %@", localDate);

NSDateFormatter *format1q = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
format1q.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";


NSString *StrDAte=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[format1q stringFromDate:utcDate]];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:StrDAte];
date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60];

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
NSString *pmamDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```